# Battery Status Not Displayed on Ubuntu 12.04 for toshiba laptop

Tags: notification-area, toshiba-satellite

I am using a Toshiba Satellite L650 and I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS installed with all the updates. However, I cannot see the battery status in the notification area.

Comment: i had did what you said and i can not find the option you have provided in the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Go to the gear button in the upper corner select the system settings in the drop down menu.
Once you are there select power then look for this[image]